# My Signed APK Crash when i read or write data from Firebase Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Basically i am using Both Firestore and Firebase realtime in my App. Once user signup in my app i saved user UID in realtime and than my recycler view fetch some category icon and name from my Firestore. Everything is working fine when i test my app on emulator directly from Android Studio
but when i generate Signed APK and when i install this app on mobile or emulator it show error when i signup the user.

Authentication System works fine user Email and UID is created Sucessfully in Firebase Auth system but realtime database not collecting data from my App Model classes.

I hope you will understand my problem

[image]

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: no sir logcat is correct and working fine but when i use download my app from playstore or use signed apk than it shows error

Comment: That's a crash. That's why I asked for a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding these lines in my app gradle build (Build Types) Section:

```
shrinkResources false
    minifyEnabled false
    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
```